# jQuery combogrid identify the input box on selection of a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using combogrid https://github.com/powderblue/jquery-combogrid to show suggestions while typing.

```
$(".stresses").combogrid({
        url: '/index/stresssearch',
        debug: true,
        colModel: [{'columnName': 'id', 'hidden': true, 'width': '1', 'label': 'id'},{'columnName': 'name', 'width': '39', 'label': 'Name'}],
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.email);
            return false;
        },

    });
```

In the above code on selecting a row, I need to assign that value to the input box. The input boxes are dynamically generated using jQuery. How can I identify the input box within the `select` function? `$(this).val()` is not working.

Comment: Try `$(event.target).val()`

Comment: Can you show how you are generating the textboxes. A fiddle/snippet is more helpful to help you.

Comment: @marekful $(event.target) is working. But the problem is since the input boxes are added dynamically, combogrid was not working. So I created the  combogrid on its parent div. So now all the input boxes within the div will have combogrid. $(event.target) is giving the parent div.

Comment: Create a Fiddle or a snipped here.

Comment: It looks you are mixing the two sides of the assignment. You probably want `$(ui.item.email).val( $(event.target).val() )`.

Comment: @marekful      I solved it by using jQuery `on` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding jQuery `on` function.

```
$('body').on('focus', '.dynstresses', function () { 
    $(this).combogrid({
        url: '/index/stresssearch',
        debug: true,
        colModel: [{'columnName': 'id', 'hidden': true, 'width': '1', 'label': 'id'},{'columnName': 'name', 'width': '39', 'label': 'Name'}],
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(event.target).val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },

    });
    });
```